# Keep failing test for Answer model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a reddit clone for a class project and my Answer model is consistently failing its test.

answer_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Answer, type: :model do
    let(:question) { Question.create!(title: "New Question Title", body: "New Question Body", resolved: false) }
    let(:answer) { Answer.create!(body: "New Answer Body", question: question) }

    describe "attributes" do
        it "has a body attribute" do
            expect(Answer).to have_attributes(body: "New Answer Body")
        end
   end
end
```

I'm getting the resulting failure when I run this:

```
Failures:

1) Answer attributes has a body attribute
 Failure/Error: expect(Answer).to have_attributes(body: "New Answer Body")
   expected Answer(id: integer, body: text, questions_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) to respond to :body with 0 arguments
 # ./spec/models/answer_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02163 seconds (files took 1.94 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/answer_spec.rb:8 # Answer attributes has a body attribute
```

Could someone kindly help me with this?

Thanks.

**Edit**

Apologies for not including answer class

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: Without seeing the code to your Answer class, not much help can be given. But the test result states the issue, your Answer class doesn’t respond to “body”, meaning it has no property called body on it.

Comment: `expect(answer)`.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the expectation on the `Answer` class - not the instance defined in your `let` block.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Answer, type: :model do
    let(:question) { Question.create!(title: "New Question Title", body: "New Question Body", resolved: false) }
    let(:answer) { Answer.create!(body: "New Answer Body", question: question) }

    describe "attributes" do
        it "has a body attribute" do
            expect(answer).to have_attributes(body: "New Answer Body")
        end
   end
end
```

Althrough I would just write it as:

```
expect(answer.body).to eq "New Answer Body"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't using your `:answer` instance from your let statement.

Try this instead `answer` lowercase:

```rb
expect(answer).to have_attributes(body: "New Answer Body")
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Tried that but now I'm getting `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute `question_id``. Any idea where that is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295710/activemodelmissingattributeerror-cant-write-unknown-attribute-ad-id-with-f) might be helpful. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128651/activemodelmissingattributeerror-cant-write-unknown-attribute-user-id) too. Does your `answers` table have a `question_id` in `schema.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your database schema is different. It uses id, title, body, etc for
   question and a foreign key question_id for answers. You are not
   specifying this id for a relationship to be established. You are
   just passing a whole object instead of key. Use factory girl instead
   and specify associations if you like it this way, or just pass foreign key.
2. Another point which have already been pointed out earlier by other
   commenters. You test instance object not a class object to have an
   attribute. A class is an object of ruby Class, it would have
   property of ruby's Class not your class so use instance of your
   class to test behavior.